# Does the data allow us to conclude at the 1% significance level that more than 60% of the cars are automatic?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

We are given a spreadsheet with data on cars, n = 42. Some cars are either automatic, or manual. I have concluded from the data that 0.53281 of cars in the sample are Automatic, and the rest are manual. So far I have a null hypothesis of mu <= .6 and an alternative hypothesis of mu > .6

With the Z observation formula I am trying, I need to know the standard deviation, but I don't think I can calculate the sample standard deviation since the data is either a 0 or 1.

Comment: If your calculation of the sample proportion was right, then given the proportion in the sample is smaller than 0.6 you're not going to reject the null at any reasonable significance level; you'd need some indication in the sample that the null wasn't tenable, but 0.53281 is smaller than 0.6, perfectly in accord with it. However, you cannot get a proportion of 0.53281 with n=42 -- check your calculation (and your typing). You can calculate the standard deviation of a collection of 0's and 1's but you should have a formula for the standard deviation of a proportion.

Comment: Is this an exercise question? http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: In the event of rejection of null hypothesis as specified , we can not say alt mu greater than 0.6

Comment: contd. we can not say mu is greater than .6.